# Evitar que despues de cerrar sesión se pueda pasar a la pagina anterior en ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Buen día.

Tengo un detalle, tengo un sistema en el cual tengo un botón para cerrar sesión de la misma aplicación, lo que necesito es que al estar de nuevo en el login, no me deje pasar a la pagina anterior, un punto a comentar es que solamente me funciona cuando aun no hago ningún envío de información a la base de datos, en cambio cuando si grabo información desde el sistema, me permite hacer el retroceso a la pagina.

Tengo este código en el login.

```
            if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
            if ( Request.Cookies["userLogin"] != null)
            {
                HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("userLogin");
                myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
            }
            if ( (string)Session["userLogin"] != null)
            {
                Session.Remove("userLogin");
            }
        }
```

Y en mi formulario donde grabo la información tengo este código:

```
        Session["userLogin"] = null;
        Session.Clear();
        Response.Cookies.Clear();
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        Response.Redirect("LoginSMTValidation.aspx");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
```

Esto es en el load del formulario que envía la información:

```
        if(Session["userLogin"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/LoginSMTValidation.aspx");
        }
        txtScanModel.Focus();
```

Aparte lo he estado intentando tambien con funciones de JS:

```
    function noBack() { window.history.forward(1) }
    setTimeout("noBack()", 0);
    noBack();
    window.onload = noBack;
    window.onpageshow = function (evt) { if (evt.persisted) noBack() }
    window.onunload = function () { void (0) }
    if (history.forward(1)) {
        location.replace(history.forward(1))
    }
```

Que puedo tener mal o que me faltaría agregar alguna función o algo asi

Answer (score 0):

Del lado de cliente puedes agregar el valor de una variable global algo como EnSession = true y cuando no estes firmado eso pase a falso a hora en tu pagina para no regresar puedes agregar lo siguiente:

```
if(String(window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type) === "back_forward"){
    if(!EnSession)
     {
         //redirige a login.
        }
}\\\
```

Comment: no me funciono hermano, ahorita hice pruebas y hasta por solo capturar un dato, sin enviar ese dato a la base de datos, me sigue regresando aun cuando le doy logout

Comment: Simplifica y agrega tu codigo solo para esa etapa. Para saber como estas llamando la parte en donde ya hiciste logout.